Product over primitive roots of unity
I am trying to solve a non-zero contour integral passing over all poles of $\frac1{z^n-1}$ but I got a bit stuck on a point involving an nth product over some primitive roots of unity. I denoted $\zeta_n$ as the primitive root of unity of $n$-degree.
$ \oint_{\phi_n}\frac{dz}{z^n-1} =2i\pi \sum_{1\leq k\leq n} \lim_{z \to \zeta_n^k} \frac{z-\zeta_n^k}{z^n-1} $
From the fundamental theorem of algebra
$ \because z^n-1=(z-1)(z-\zeta_n)(z-\zeta_n^2)\ldots(z-\zeta_n^{n-1}) $
$  \oint_{\phi_n}\frac{dz}{z^n-1} =2i\pi \sum_{1\leq k\leq n} \lim_{z \to \zeta_n^k} \frac{z-\zeta_n^k}{(z-1)(z-\zeta_n)(z-\zeta_n^2)\ldots(z-\zeta_n^{n-1})} $
By expanding it, the integral will become:
$ \frac I{2i\pi}= \frac{1}{(\zeta_n-1)(\zeta_n-\zeta_n^2)...(\zeta_n-\zeta_n^{n-1})} +\frac{ 1 }{(\zeta_n^2-1)(\zeta_n^2-\zeta_n)(\zeta_n^2-\zeta_n^3)...(\zeta_n^2-\zeta_n^{n-1})}+  
\cdots+\frac{1}{ (1-\zeta_n^2)...(1-\zeta_n^{n-1}) } $
And now I'm stuck, I don’t know how to solve the products in the denominator, I thought of using the cyclotomic polynomials, but I'm not too sure how to use it.

What is the contour $\phi_n$?

It's contour i made, it passes over each pole

Just a small remark, but using d'Alembert-Gauss theorem (which anglo-saxons refer as fundamental theorem of algebra) for an explicit factorisation is overkill

I know... thought I could relate the integral to the cyclotomic polynomials this way...

Method 1: Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to\zeta_n^k} \frac{z-\zeta_n^k}{z^n-1}$ using l'Hôpital's rule.
Method 2: Instead of using the residue theorem, expand the contour so that it is an enormous circle, and estimate the contour directly—you should get a bound that goes to $0$ as the radius of the circle tends to infinity.

Unfortunately the contour is a really complicated one, it involves certain elliptic functions. But using l'Hopital isn’t a bad option. Thanks.
